# How do I refer to the values in this string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object with one String value in it in javascript.  I believe it should be a key value pair but something is changing it so that this doesn't work:

```
$.each(object, function(index, element) {
  if (element.key) {
    //do something with element.key and element.value
  }
}
```

The value of element when inspecting with firebug is:

```
[Object { STRING="1=stringValue"}]
```

How do I process this object?

Comment: Where is the object coming from? What do you expect it to contain?

Comment: it's hard to know how to traverse the object without knowing its structure. Do you have a representation of what `object` is?

Comment: I expect it to contain a key value pair.

Comment: @coder: Well, yes. That's what comprises an object. Is this *your* object? Do you know what the keys are?

Comment: I think the Object is Collection<Entry<String, String>>

Comment: @coder: So you think it's an Array of Objects? You don't seem to know many specifics about its structure. Where is the object coming from?

Comment: It is a json representation of a Collection<Entry<String, String>> which is sent to the client as "objectName":[{STRING:"1=stringValue"}]

Comment: @amnotiam does that clarify?  I can get the string from this, but I'm not sure how to process the "1=stringValue".

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var key in object){
   if(!object.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
   var value = object[key];
   // now you have the key and value.
}
```

Comment: I recommend a `hasOwnProperty` check to guard against inherited enumerable properties.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Why? You don't actually weigh down all of your enumeration with an unnecessary guard, do you? The `hasOwnProperty` method should be used when you *know* there are prototyped enumerable properties that you specifically want to avoid.

Comment: @amnotiam I don't enumerate with `for..in`. A third-party script may add an enumerable property to `Object.prototype`. Just because you (as the "first party") don't do it doesn't mean that your `for..in` statements are safe.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Sure they're safe. If a 3rd party script places an enumerable on `Object.prototype`, you remove that script. Extending `Object.prototype` is a pretty darn good litmus test for JS code quality.

Comment: @amnotiam Circumstances my not allow that. You may work in a company that relies on such a script. Btw extending the native prototypes can be acceptable if it's done right (and for the right reasons).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Those would be narrow and unusual circumstances. We wouldn't want to make broad coding suggestions based on such. And I have no problem with generally extending native prototypes. Specifically extending `Object.prototype` with enumerable properties is a whole other matter. But that doesn't mean we should give `for-in` a blanket label of unsafe.

Comment: @amnotiam What about instances of custom constructors (like `function Foo () {...} var foo = new Foo();`)? the properties of prototypes of such constructors (`Foo.prototype` in this case) are predominantly enumerable, which means that doing a `for..in` over such an instance object would include all those inherited method property names.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Please see my first comment where I said *"The `hasOwnProperty` method should be used when you know there are prototyped enumerable properties that you specifically want to avoid."* None of these examples have anything to do with your original suggestion to use `hasOwnProperty` on an arbitrary object.

Comment: @amnotiam My logic is this: A `for..in` statement enumerates all (enumerable) properties of an object (own properties and inherited properties). For a given object, if only its own properties are of interest, then a `hasOwnProperty` check has to be included to indicate that. The code has to communicate clearly, and any confusion must be avoided. If you omit the `hasOwnProperty` check, then it's not not clear from the code whether only own properties are of interest, or whether the intent is to process (possible) inherited properties as well.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: *"if only its own properties are of interest, then a `hasOwnProperty` check has to be included..."* I disagree. When you enumerate, you need some foreknowledge of what you're enumerating. You can't just blindly use `hasOwnProperty`, because it could be that you *do* want the prototyped enumerables. So if you have that foreknowledge, but want to communicate it for clarity, just use a code comment. And if you know there are prototyped enumerables to avoid, use `hasOwnProperty`. And if you just don't know the nature of the object, then you need to find out.

Comment: ...this question is a good example. How do we know that prototyped properties should be excluded? We don't. If the user hits something prototyped that isn't desired, then the user needs to act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
Object.keys( obj ).forEach( function ( key ) {
    key // the property name
    obj[ key ] // the value of that property
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/eyPDA/2/

If you need to iterate over the own properties of an object, then `Object.keys( obj ).forEach(...` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling the objects toString method and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the printout, the key is `STRING`, so `object.STRING` or `object["STRING"]` will get you your value if `object` refers to the object that actually has contains the string.  However, it appears that `element` is actually a 1-element array of objects, so `element[0].STRING` should work instead of `element.key`.

Comment: well, it looks like `[Object { STRING="1=stringValue"}]` is an array whose first element is the object you describe.

Comment: And he is already iterating over the array, so inside the function, element refers to the object.

Comment: but he stated, "The value of element" is that array, what I'm saying is he'd have to do: element[0].STRING